# Can users close questions regardless?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Is the community of users allowed to vote to close a question for no particularly good reason?

For example if a lot of people see a question they don't like (and want to close it), and none of the existing close reasons seem to be a perfect fit, can they pick existing close reasons anyway and vote to close it?

If they do, will the question stay closed? Or will other people (and moderators) say, "Well that close reason doesn't really fit, therefore the question doesn't deserve to be closed for that reason, therefore the question should be reopened?"

I guess I'm wondering, which is more important:

- Keeping questions open, ensuring that any closures are "fair", by ensuring that questions are closed only for pre-approved reasons, e.g. to avoid censorship
- Letting the "community of users" choose to close it if they will, regardless

Or maybe you don't have a firm rule about that, so "it depends" (perhaps, "it depends" on whether *you* think the question "should" to be reopened)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question should not be closed without a reason on any stack exchange site. Maybe people don't like it - I accept that - but then it is on *them* to explain why.

Maybe there can be the exceptional case where the existing boilerplate reasons do not fit - there's always the chance to use a custom reason.

[image]

Of course, if there is no clear harm done by the question, or no real explanations, moderators and other users will reopen. Special cases can be discussed in meta.